# RESOLVED: Laravel - Can't make "submit form" route to show up

Tags: laravel

RESOLVED!

I just needed to access "links.test/submit" instead of simply "links.test", as "submit.blade.php" was a new page.

I also learned the tutorial uses an older version of Laravel, meaning "resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php" was not created because the

`php artisan make:auth`

command did not work. For Laravel 7, as Gustavo Alves pointed out, I needed to use these two commands instead:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am going through a Laravel tutorial for beginners - https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application. I came to the "Displaying the Link Submission Form" section and pasted the provided code snippet into the routes/web.php file, then created submit.blade.php template at resources/views/submit.blade.php with the provided code snippet, as per instructions.

However, the submit form is NOT showing up in my "links.test".

web.php:

```
?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $links = \App\Link::all();

    return view('welcome', ['links' => $links]);
});

Route::get('/submit', function () {
    return view('submit');
});
```

submit.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h1>Submit a Link </h1>
            <form action="/submit" method="post" >
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        Plese fix the following errors
                    </div>
                @endif
{!!csrf_field()!!}
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
                    @if($errors->has('title'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {{ $errors->first('title') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('url') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="url">Url</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="URL" value="{{ old('url') }}">
                    @if($errors->has('url'))
                        <span>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ $errors->first('url') }}
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="description">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
                    @if($errors->has('description'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ $errors->first('description') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: what are you using as server environment?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I am a complete beginner at BE, so I am not even sure how to check that. I only know I am using Laravel's Valet (as I am on Mac).

Comment: look at this site: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet

Comment: When following the tutorial, did `php artisan make:auth` worked? I think not, because this command was removed on Laravel 6. If that's the case, see this here(https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-changes-in-php-artisan-ui-auth-php-artisan-make-auth-82fdb8893726) how to accomplish this on recent versions.

Comment: I feel like it's a problem connected with "@extends('layouts.app')". But going through https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade documentation still hasn't helped me yet.

Comment: @ usrNotFound Tried it. No result.

Comment: do you have a section called `content` on your `layouts.app`?

Comment: @usrNotFound I am just checked and I am missing the layouts.app itself! Along with other contents that should be in the "resources -> views" folder. I only have "welcome.blade.php" and (just created by me) "submit.blade.php there.

Comment: @Gustavo Alves You were right. I started a new project and `php artisan make:auth` did not work because I have Laravel 7. I must have missed the error message when I tried it before. That's why I was missing files like `esources\views\layouts\app.blade.php`. However, I used new commands that work with my version of Laravel (got the `layouts/app.blade.php` installed) but I still can't make the `submit.blade.php` to show up in the `nameofmyproject.test`.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I can gather for your comment is

you need to create `resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php` where you will have something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Your App</title>

@section('head')
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

@show()

</head>
<body>

@yield('content')

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>

@show

@endsection

</body>
</html>
```

Once you got this you should be able to extend and this should work as well.

Comment: I created a new project which has the resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php (with `@yield('content')`) and retraced the steps but still... nothing. I can change "welcome.blade.php" as much as I please but "submit.blade.php" refuses to route. I am starting to think there might a problem with the tutorial - it might not be working with the latest Laravel version I have.

Comment: I will need to check you code before I say anything if you don't mind sharing. Share me the link to the repo. I can have a look at it if you want

Comment: ＠usrNotFound, thank you very much for offering to look at the code. I just realized what the problem was by going through Laravel tutorials on Youtube. Turns out, as a complete beginner I did not realize I needed to open the "submit" as a new page and that's what ```Route::get('/submit', function () {
    return view('submit');
});``` meant. Now I am wiser! Thank you for offering help!